# Different layers Div lightbox effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a lightbox effect. Showing Images to the user with a GridView. After clicking one of the image, there should be another layer show above the current page and give a bigger image with description. I managed to show the layer with image and its content but everything is transparent. i tried set the opacity to 1 and move other element to higher z-index, but nothing works

here is my CSS code

```
#imageshown{
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
width:1000px;
height:600px;
background:#000;
opacity:0.8;
}

#imageshown > img{
opacity:1;
z-index:2;
position:relative;
top:15px;
width:450px;
height:450px;
margin:0 auto;

}

#image_content{
opacity:1;
z-index:2;
position:relative;
top:15px;
width:450px;
height:100px;
margin:0 auto;
background:#FFF;
 }

#exit{
position:absolute;
border-radius:50px;
background:#006;
opacity:1;
top:-5px;
left:-5px;
z-index:2;
color:white;
text-align:center;
width:30px;
height:30px;
}
```

and my Jquery code

```
$("#imggroup img").click(function(e) {
    $(document).find(".NewElement").remove();
    var ImageElement ="<img src=\"" + $(this).attr("src") + "\" alt=\"image shown\" />";
    var DivContents = "<div id=\"image_content\"> blah blah blah </div>";
    var Exit = "<div id=\"exit\" > X </div>";
    var ElementWrap = "<div id=\"imageshown\" class= \"NewElement\"> "+ ImageElement + DivContents+ Exit+"</div>";
    alert(ElementWrap);
    $("#container").prepend(ElementWrap);
});
```

I have function for exit too, but i can't click on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving opacity to a parent will cascade to all children no matter what you set their opacity to. So by setting `opacity: 0.8` on what I'm guessing is the parent container, every child will have the same opacity.

One way to get transparency on an element without affecting children is to use a transparent background:

```
#imageshown {
    background:#000; //leave this if you need to support IE8 and lower which don't support rgba
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
    //opacity:0.8; remove this
}
```

If you do need to support older IE and want transparency, you can use the fallback here: http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/.

```
#imageshown { 
    background:transparent;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#50000000,endColorstr=#50000000); //first two numbers are transparency and based on hex values
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I just add `background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);`